# Custom Lock is not working in Docker

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

I have developed SocketBased locking and this is working perfectly if i deploy karaf Non-Docker environment, but when i try this in docker its not showing anything. infact if i start in debug mode following line is not printing

```
DEBUG | Karaf Lock Monitor Thread | Main                             |  -  -  | Waiting for the lock ...
```

Debug Logs of Non-Docker Deployment

```
un 28, 2018 11:52:07 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main launch 
INFO: Installing and starting initial bundles 
Jun 28, 2018 11:52:07 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main launch 
INFO: All initial bundles installed and set to start 
2018-06-28T11:52:08,652 | INFO  | Karaf Lock Monitor Thread | SocketLock                       |  -  -  | in override lock() method 
2018-06-28T11:52:08,662 | INFO  | Karaf Lock Monitor Thread | SocketLock                       |  -  -  | in override isAlive() method 
2018-06-28T11:52:08,663 | DEBUG | Karaf Lock Monitor Thread | Main                             |  -  -  | Waiting for the lock ... 
2018-06-28T11:52:08,703 | DEBUG | CM Configuration Updater (Update: pid=org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn) | mvn                              | 4 - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn - 2. 
5.4 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.MavenResolver] - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn 
2018-06-28T11:52:08,706 | DEBUG | CM Configuration Updater (Update: pid=org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn) | mvn                              | 4 - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn - 2. 
5.4 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService] - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn 
2018-06-28T11:52:08,716 | DEBUG | pool-2-thread-2  | core                             | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.1.5 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [o 
rg.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver.ResolverHookFactory] - org.apache.karaf.features.core
```

Following are Logs when i start karaf in Docker

```
Jun 28, 2018 11:33:56 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main launch 
INFO: Installing and starting initial bundles 
Jun 28, 2018 11:33:56 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main launch 
INFO: All initial bundles installed and set to start 
2018-06-28T11:33:57,166 | DEBUG | FelixStartLevel  | core                             | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.1.5 | BundleEvent STARTED - org.apach 
e.karaf.features.core 
2018-06-28T11:33:57,181 | DEBUG | FelixDispatchQueue | Main                             |  -  -  | Start level change complete. 
2018-06-28T11:33:57,182 | DEBUG | FelixDispatchQueue | framework                        | 0 - org.apache.felix.framework - 5.6.10 | FrameworkEvent STARTLEVEL CHANGED 
 - org.apache.felix.framework 
2018-06-28T11:33:57,516 | DEBUG | CM Configuration Updater (Update: pid=org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn) | mvn                              | 4 - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn - 2.5.4 
 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.MavenResolver] - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn 
2018-06-28T11:33:57,520 | DEBUG | CM Configuration Updater (Update: pid=org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn) | mvn                              | 4 - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn - 2.5.4 
 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService] - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn 
2018-06-28T11:33:57,532 | DEBUG | pool-2-thread-2  | core                             | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.1.5 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org. 
osgi.framework.hooks.resolver.ResolverHookFactory] - org.apache.karaf.features.core 
2018-06-28T11:33:57,536 | DEBUG | pool-2-thread-2  | core                             | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.1.5 | ServiceEvent REGISTERED - [org. 
osgi.framework.hooks.bundle.CollisionHook] - org.apache.karaf.features.core
```

Answer (score 0):

My custom lock code was throwing some error due to which karaf lock was not 
working, i just try-catch exception and now its working.